# Changes to max_input_vars in my php.ini aren't reflecting

Tags: php

I found the location of my php.ini file on my windows server and changed the max_input_vars line from 1000 to 3000 and changed post_max_size to 16m and rebooted my server.  Now, the post_max_size changed, but the max_input_vars didn't when I check phpinfo.

I even searched my server for other variations of my php.ini file and changed max_input_users in those, as well, including php.ini.development and another one.  Still no change when I look at my phpinfo.

I also thought maybe sehosin was installed, so I added the lines:

```
suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000
```

Still, my max_input_vars = 1000.

How does one change this value??

Comment: As stated above, not sure, however I never installed it so unless it came with the latest version of php for iis then no.  I searched for it in phpinfo, but it wasn't there either.  I added the two lines above to my php.ini in case I did have it.  Still didn't work.

Comment: Is there a cache I need to clear?  Something with FastCGI?  Could I somehow change the max_input_vars with the web.config?  I don't know, throwing ideas out there...